# Does anyone have an example of how to stream the camera to a server on android?

Tags: android, streaming, live

I find plenty of examples of downstreaming a video from a server to an android, but I actually want to stream live images from my droid to a server.

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Qik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qik) claims to do this. But as I am now reading the Wikipedia article more closely, it says that it doesn't really do *live* streaming for the iPhone or for Android.

For iPhone, it starts uploading after the recording has finished, and for Android, there are 15-20 seconds delay (according to Wikipedia).

So it seems if not even those Qik guys, who seem to have experience with live streaming, can do it, it's a very hard problem.

On the other hand, I have not tried Qik. Maybe you can install and test it, and do some traffic sniffing with Wireshark to see how they do it on the network level.